# clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.Associative

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure and I tried to implement a genetic algorithm. Thus, I've got a problem, the implementation keeps throwing the following error:

```
class clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.Associative (clojure.lang.LazySeq and clojure.lang.Associative are in unnamed module 
of loader 'app')
```

To be mentioned that each function is tested individually in REPL and returns the correct results but after putting them all together, the error is thrown, and I don't understand it since it doesn't seems to specify a line number.

The version of clojure is the one from master branch and built with maven, on Windows.

The full code:

```
(ns ga)

(defn new-individual
    [genome-length]
    {:genome (vec (repeatedly genome-length #(rand-int 2))) :fitness 0}
    )


(defn fitness-function
    [genome, target]
    (Math/abs (- (reduce + genome) target))
)




(defn calculate-fitness
    [population, target]
    (defn fitness-function-helper 
        [individual, target]
        (assoc individual :fitness (fitness-function (individual :genome) target))
    )
        (map (fn [individual] (#(fitness-function-helper individual target))) population)
)



(defn crossover
        [first-individual, second-individual, crossover-rate, target]
        (let [new-genome (map (fn [i1,i2] (let [crossover-probability (rand)]
                                        (cond
                                            (<= crossover-probability crossover-rate) i1
                                            :else i2
                                        )
                                    )
                            ) 
            (first-individual :genome) (second-individual :genome)
                )]
            {:genome new-genome :fitness (fitness-function new-genome target)}
        )
        
)
        


(defn mutate
  [individual, genome-length, target]
  (let [new-genome (assoc (individual :genome) (rand-int genome-length) (rand-int 2))]
    {:genome new-genome :fitness (fitness-function new-genome target)}
  )
)



(defn better
  [i1 i2]
  (< (i1 :fitness) (i2 :fitness)))

(defn tournament-selection
  [population, population-size, steps, tournament-size, new-population, target]
  (if (< steps tournament-size)
    (recur population population-size (inc steps) tournament-size (conj new-population (nth population ((comp rand-int -) population-size 2))) target
      
     )
        ;(println new-population)
        (first (sort better (calculate-fitness new-population target)))
        
    )
)

(defn new-generation [population, population-size, crossover-rate, target, tournament-size]
    (loop [steps 0 new-population ()]
        (if (< steps population-size)
        (let [i1 (tournament-selection population population-size 0 tournament-size () target)]
            (let [i2 (tournament-selection population population-size 0 tournament-size () target)]
                (let [offs (crossover i1 i2 crossover-rate target)]
                    (recur (inc steps) (conj new-population offs))
                )
            )
        )
        new-population
    )
        )
    )
    
    (defn new-mutated-generation [population, population-size, genome-length, target]
        (loop [steps 0 new-population ()]
            (if (< steps population-size)
                    (recur (inc steps) (conj new-population (mutate (nth population steps) genome-length target)))
                    new-population
            )

        )

    )
        

(defn evolve [population-size, genome-length, target]
(let [population (calculate-fitness (repeatedly population-size #(new-individual genome-length)) target)]
    (let [offsprings (new-generation population population-size 0.5 target 5)]
        (println (new-mutated-generation offsprings population-size genome-length target))
        )
    


)

)

(evolve 10 5 5)
```

Comment: To get the exception, just evaluate `*e` in your REPL. Also, don't nest `defn` and/or `def` statements. If you need to create a function within a function, use `let`+`fn` or `letfn`.

Comment: @EugenePakhomov Thanks for the advice. I'll keep in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stacktrace reveals that the problematic code is the line

```clj
(let [new-genome (assoc (vec (individual :genome)) (rand-int genome-length) (rand-int 2))]
```

and more specifically, the call to `assoc`. If we edit the code by inserting the following line just above:

```clj
(println "Individual: " (individual :genome) ", " (class (individual :genome)))
```

it prints out

```
Individual:  (0 1 1 0 1) ,  clojure.lang.LazySeq
```

The problem is that `assoc` cannot be used with lazy sequences (`clojure.lang.LazySeq`) because it does not implement the [clojure.lang.Associative](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Associative.java) interface which is needed by [assoc](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L824).

This lazy sequence is constructed by the call to `map` on this line:

```clj
(let [new-genome (map (fn [i1,i2] (let [crossover-probability (rand)]
```

If you replace [map](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) by [mapv](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mapv) so that the code looks like this

```clj
(let [new-genome (mapv (fn [i1,i2] (let [crossover-probability (rand)]
```

the code will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and for the explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Error happens in the function `mutate`. It has this source:

```
(defn mutate
  [individual, genome-length, target]
  (let [new-genome (assoc (individual :genome) (rand-int genome-length) (rand-int 2))]
    {:genome new-genome :fitness (fitness-function new-genome target)}))
```

In one step, you are calling it with these arguments: `{:genome (0 1 1 1 1), :fitness 1} 5 5` (genome can have different value, but it's always sequence of numbers).

`(individual :genome)` returns `(0 1 1 1 1)` (sequence) and then you used [`assoc`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc), which is function for hash maps or vectors.

Genome is vector at the beginning, but it's converted into sequence in `crossover` function- use [`mapv`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mapv) instead of `map` here:

```
(defn crossover
  [first-individual, second-individual, crossover-rate, target]
  (let [new-genome (mapv (fn [i1, i2] (let [crossover-probability (rand)]
                                        (if (<= crossover-probability crossover-rate) i1 i2)))
                         (first-individual :genome) (second-individual :genome))]
    {:genome new-genome :fitness (fitness-function new-genome target)}))
```

By the way, all parentheses at the end of definition belong at the same line.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and for the explanations.